# Service Fabric: System.IndexOutOfRangeException - 'System.RA' reported Warning for property 'ReplicaOpenStatus'

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless, service-fabric-on-premises

I am trying to deploy a Stateless application on my service fabric cluster. As soon as the application is deployed, it goes to warning and then error state with the following error:

> 'System.RA' reported Warning for property 'ReplicaOpenStatus'. Replica
> had multiple failures during open on _nt1vm_4. API call:
> IStatelessServiceInstance.Open(); Error =
> System.IndexOutOfRangeException (-2146233080) Index was outside the
> bounds of the array.    at
> System.Fabric.Common.Tracing.FabricEventSource.ExtensionsEventsInternal.WriteWarning(String
> id, String type, String message)    at
> Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Runtime.StatelessServiceInstanceAdapter.<System.Fabric.IStatelessServiceInstance.OpenAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
> For more information see: https://aka.ms/sfhealth

This is happening on both my local SF cluster and when its deployed on Azure. Since it is not even entering the main program in the application, I am not able to see any other meaningful log or events. I have also logged into the remote node and looked at the logs, didn't find anything other than this.
The source of this error is not clear from this message and I'm not able to debug without application logs.

[service fabric application error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDqhO.png)

Comment: This can also happen when a communication listener is failing to open. Are you trying to run multiple listeners on the same port maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at two things:

1. Have you made any changes to the ServiceEventSource such that it's accessing an invalid (negative) index when writing out values?
2. In your RunAsync method in your entry class of whatever service is faulting, wrap the whole of it in a try/catch and set a breakpoint where the exception throws - if it runs through without error, it at least narrows where the underlying issue is coming from.